# How can I compare two unordered sequences (list and array) for equality?

Tags: c#, linq

I have string array say `string str[] = {"a", "b"}`

and `List<string> lst = new List<string> {"a", "b"}`

How can I make sure that both string array and list contains the same values. *Note: The values can be in any order but must have the same frequency.*

Can anyone tell me how to do it in LINQ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do they need to be in the same order?

Comment: Do (a) order and (b) count matter?

Comment: @jason no, it can be in any order..

Comment: @Bhaskar K: Wait, the frequencies matter?

Comment: @Jason Yep. count should be the same for the both and should have the same values.

Comment: If both list are completely the same.. isn't it easier to just cast the List to a Array and visa versa?  
Like:  var str = lst.ToArray() and var lst = str.ToList() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, since order does not matter but frequncies do, you need to count each key, and then check that the resulting pairs of keys/counts are equal:

```
var first = str.GroupBy(s => s)
               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

var second = lst.GroupBy(s => s)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

bool equals = first.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                   .SequenceEquals(second.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key));
```

Comment: why first do a `GroupBy` when you do an ordered `SequenceEquals` on both collections afterwards anyway? You can skip that imo.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you just

- Sort both (since order is irrelevant for you)
- Compare the results with `SequenceEqual()`¹

Saves the dictionary approach of Jason (which, obviously, should work as well) and seems more natural/easy to me?

①: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer seems somewhat awkward to me. Why can't you just do:

```
bool equals = str.OrderBy(s => s).SequenceEquals(lst.OrderBy(t => t));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Enumerable.SequenceEqual

```
  string[] str =new [] {"a", "b"};
  List<string> lst = new List<string> {"a", "b"};
  bool result=str.SequenceEqual(lst);
```

Comment: He said order does NOT matter.

Comment: Ok I did not see this. I was answering the original question. I don't see the need of minus my answer for this.